# Coast Starlight delays

Tags: trains, california, amtrak, delays

I'll be taking the Coast Starlight tomorrow from Los Angeles to San Jose.

The train is supposed to arrive at 8:11pm at San Jose, but I have heard that the train is frequently (very?) late.

Is there any place where I could find "how late" the train usually is ? For example to know whether I'll be able to catch public transportation to Palo Alto or not...

Answer (score 5):

This will at least give you the on-time percentage: [on-time percentage](http://www.amtrak.com/coast-starlight-train&mode=perf&overrideDefaultTemplate=OTPPageVerticalRouteOverview). However, I don't know of anything that will give you exact numbers, but in my experience it usually ends up being 90-120 minutes if it's delayed, but it can vary widely.

Comment: It is also possible to use the "status" tab of the amtrak website to find the delay of the currently riding train to have an idea of how late it can be.

Comment: Good idea. For example, yesterday's train was 2h26m late and today's seems to be ~1h late.